# Add a method to multiple java classes at once in intellij

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

Got to add a new method to multiple java classes inside the test definition layer.
Same method should go in all the classes available inside a package, is there any way to do it all at once in intellij IDE.

Comment: Can base abstract class for your classes to resolve your issue?

Comment: This sounds like a scenario that you need to specifically design for (every class in that package should inherit or extend a base class with the method you need)e This isn't a feature that an IDE like IntelliJ should or would provide.

Comment: Use an interface and a default method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static import of the class and use the static method in that class across all the classes in that package.

Lets say you have a package ABCD with classes A,B,C,D and static method m1 of class Z to be used across package ABCD's classes.

```
package Z1;

Class Z
{
static void m1()
{
....
}
}

package ABCD;

import static Z1.Z.*;

Class A
{

void m2()
{
m1();
}

}

Class B
{

void m3()
{
m1();
}

}

Class C
{

void m3()
{
m1();
}

}
```

You can also achieve the same with help of inheritance as well.

Comment: While you have the code for `m1()` in one location so that it's DRY, the inheritance way is much better.

Comment: Yes i too agree inheritance is also a solution but even in this case the code lies in one location right. In what way it makes difference ??

Comment: In your approach, you have to add a "dummy" method to every class that does nothing but calls the other method. The inheritance way is the right way and it's also cleaner.

Comment: thanks for clarification. i got your point but i dont think so a dummy method is required every time , suppose say there is one more class D where it is not required we need not use it.                                           
As per the question asked , it does not state any IS-A relationship between all the classes which is conceptually very important to consider. Just because to use a method , it may not be correct to use inheritance. If IS-A relation ship is formed then inheritance can be considered as well.